# Storing percentages in database as decimal

Tags: mysql, database

I am developing a very simple quoting app for myself. The program uses percentages for gross margin in calculating sales costs. It can be anywhere from 1% to 100% normally but at the very most 1000% which would be an extreme edge case on its own. And it will always have 2 decimal places of accuracy.

I am currently storing it as a fractional decimal (6,4) to allow for the maximum of 1000% and the two places of decimal. However is this the correct thing to do? Is this even the correct data type for this. I considered storing as integers or even decimal but as the complete percentage rather than a fractional honestly I am a little unsure and would appreciate the wisdom of more experienced people. I do not want to end up having to change this further down the road. Am i missing anything?

Comment: What's wrong with your current aproach that you are looking for an alternative one? I believe, you are overthinking this quite a bit :)

Comment: The maximum value storable in a `decimal(6,4)` type is `+/-99.9999`. You would need `decimal(6,2)`; the `2` specifies the number of decimal places.

Comment: @Nick That would only be the case if I was storing them as whole percentages in decimal i.e 124.62% would be 124.62 that would be (6,2) but if it was fractional decimal it would be 1.2462 (6,4)

My only reason for using fractional decimal is that when I read other peoples uses of it they all seem to use fractional decimal to store percentages. But they dont explain why. Hence my post as to whether this is best practice.

Comment: @RyanWalkowski gotcha. the "1000% and 2 places of decimal" made me think you were storing it as a raw percentage. I agree with Shadow, what you're doing is fine.

Comment: @RyanWalkowski "best practice" is often in the eye of the beholder. It depends on how you need to work with the data afterwards. If a solution works for you and there is no performance problem either, then just leave it be. When you ask about best practice, you always need to define the context (no, this question's context is too broad) otherwise we cannot objectively answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

I've been grappling with this as well, creating an invoicing app which involves tax calculations with user-defined percents. I've done a good bit of research which says that decimals are indeed the correct database data type for financial calculation.

So it's down to understanding why storing 10.75% as a fractional percent `0.1075` is the best practice over storing it as a whole percent `10.75`.

As I see it, the pros for fractional percent `0.1075`:

- Simpler calculations: just multiply the amount by the fractional percent, otherwise you need to divide by 100 in every calculation. Simpler code is easier to read and maintain. I think this is the crux of the best practice.
- This is what is expected. Once a standard or best practice exists, and I believe this is considered the standard, adhering to that standard facilitates communication (between people and between APIs), sharing of code, etc.

Pros for whole percent `10.75`:

- On the flip side of the calculations being simpler with a fractional percent, when I display the percent for humans, I must now multiply by 100 in the presentation layer. This is mitigated by the host of formatting functions built into languages such at .NET, and in fact they expect a fractional percent, which goes to the "this is what is expected" pro for fractional percent. I also don't find myself formatting values for display as often as I use them in calculations.

Good luck, I think what you've landed upon is good, in line with best practice, and will serve you well into the future.